# How to store code directly in the database?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to store a line of xml in mysql and after I save it, it gets formatted with some extra characters.

```
href=\"\" index=\"My Website\" admin=\"Civillage\" default=\"Borak Obama, Mitt Romney\" country=\"USA\" age=\"\" gender=\'\' usertopicsallowed=\'no\' layout=\'line\'
```

How can I get rid of the backslashes?

Comment: Can you show us the code you are using to store it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`stripslashes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php):

```
$str = "Is your name O\'reilly?";
echo stripslashes($str);    // Outputs: Is your name O'reilly?
```

Comment: stripslashes() is not a suitable method to be used.

Answer (score 2):

just do not add them before saving your text in the database.

- check for the `magic_quotes` setting ant be sure it is turned `OFF`
- check your code for the excessive escaping. 
  only string data have to be escaped for the query and it has to be done only once.
- prepared statements shouldn't be escaped at all

Answer (score -1):

Use [`mysql_real_escape_string($s);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) on any code input you wish to store in your database, this will escape the characters successfully and not leave you with any superfluous slashes.

For this method to work, a mySQL connection must already be established.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Not sure why this has been marked down? Successfully provides a solution to the answer.  Any comments?